# How to connect Excel VBA with iMacros (Chrome extension)?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, imacros

I have a set of codes to be copied to the iMacros which is a chrome extension. So I have it on Excel. I want to put them all in a ActiveX control box and export the code to pasted to the iMacros. How is it possible? Is there any hyperlink to connect Excel and iMacros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of different options:

1. You can save the codes as a CSV file and then read the values into your macro using the available !DATASOURCE, !DATASOURCE_LINE, and !COLn variables.

For more information on reading values from a CSV file, see the following:

http://wiki.imacros.net/Form_Filling#Input_from_Comma_Separated_Data_.28CSV.29_File

2. If you want to be able to launch iMacros directly from your Excel file and pass values to your macro using VBA, then you will need to use the iMacros Enterprise scripting interface.

For more information about using the Enterprise scripting interface, see the following:

http://wiki.imacros.net/Web_Scripting

http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference#Scripting_Interface_Command_Overview

http://wiki.imacros.net/Macro_or_Script

http://wiki.imacros.net/Sample_Code#VBA